# How can display dynamic text at the center of Image into JPanel

Tags: java, swing

I have a Java swing Program and I want insert this image:

[image]

At the center, of this image, I want to insert a dynamic text like this:

> 05:00 (this is a timer)

So I have build this code:

```
public void getLabel(){
    labelTempoGara = new TimeRefreshRace();
    labelTempoGara.setForeground(Color.white);
    labelTempoGara.start();
}
    class TimeRefreshRace extends JLabel implements Runnable {

        private boolean isAlive = false;

        public void start() {
            threadTempoCorsa = new Thread(this);
            isAlive = true;
            threadTempoCorsa.start();
        }

        public void run() {
            int tempoInSecondi = programma.getTempoGara() % 60;
            int minuti = programma.getTempoGara() / 60;
            while (isAlive) {
                try {
                    if (minuti <= 0 && tempoInSecondi<=1) {
                        isRun=false;
                        this.setText("00:00");
                        isAlive = false;
                        salvaDatiCorsa();
                        break;
                    }
                    if(tempoInSecondi<=1){
                        minuti--;
                        tempoInSecondi=60;
                    }
                    --tempoInSecondi;
                    this.setText(minuti+":"+ tempoInSecondi);
                    Thread.sleep(1000);

                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    log.logStackTrace(e);
                }
            }
        }

        public void kill() {
            isAlive = false;
            isRun=false;
        }

    }//fine autoclass
```

Now how can I insert this label at the center of my Image and diplay it on my JPanel???

Comment: "Now how can I insert this label at the center of my Image and diplay it on my JPanel???": where is the JPanel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the outer image in a `JLabel`, apply a `BorderLayout` or `GridBagLayout` to it, add your timer label to it. Also, you're violating the thread rules of Swing by updating the state of the component from outside the context of the EDT.

See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details

Instead, you might consider using a Swing `Timer` or `SwingWorker` depending on what you hope to achieve

See [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) and [Worker Threads and SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) for more details